# Filtering custom adapter on more than one condition

Tags: android, android-listview, custom-adapter, android-filterable

I am looking for something like a compound NSPredict but for Android. I have a listView populated with data with different attribute. Currently, I can only filter on one condition say name. What I want to do is to make it possible for user to search with more just the name.

Comment: this is `Filter#performFiltering(CharSequence constraint)` what is used for that

Comment: @pskink I am able to use it to search for a string within a column of a table. What I need is to make it searchable from say two or three columns in the table.

Comment: Never mind, I have figured it out. Thanks